# akka-http url chaining always giving 404

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to create an REST api using akka-http server.
The REST endpoint is : **/user/auth/save [POST method accepting from data]** 
I've tried below code segments:

```
return post(() -> route(path("/user/auth/save", () -> formFieldList(fields -> {
            return complete("The form fields are " + fields);
        })))).seal();
```

As ususal, it doesn't work. 
Then I tried to implement routing tree :

```
return post(() -> route(path("usr", () -> route(path("auth", () -> formFieldList(fields -> {
            return complete("The form fields are " + fields);
        })))))).seal();
```

Even this one not seems to be working.
What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: are your other routes working? ie GET requests without a body parser?

Comment: whatever the method type i.e. GET/POST/PUT etc, only url like '/usr' is working....the moment i'm giving url like 'usr/something' its getting 404

Answer (score 0):

Although I never use the Java API, I was able to match the route by using `PathMatchers` within the route as follows:

```
    return route(
            path(PathMatchers.segment("usr").slash("auth").slash("save"), () ->
                post(() ->
                    complete("it works!")))
    );
```

This matched properly, and returned the expected response.

A directive is available for this situation:

`PathMatchers.separateOnSlashes("usr/auth/save")`

Comment: wont this also allow "usr%20Fauth%20Fsave" (space instead of '/')?